# Gulp.src(): where to read files?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have the following code, but it can't read files from src folder. Does anyone know the path where gulp read file from?

```
   gulp.task('default', function() {
        return gulp.src(__dirname + './src/*')
                   .pipe() ...//other code
    });
```

Folder structure:

```
--app
  --gulp
    --gulpfile.js
    --src
      --(files-to-be-read, for example: 1.png)
```

Comment: Lose the __dirname, or use path.join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The __dirname global returns the current directory and will not include aditional slash at the end, so concatenating `'./otherDir'` will become `'/dir./otherDir'`.
Just remove the dot from the string to concatenate.
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html

Comment: Thanks. I just fixed it. But I still have question about how gulp find the folder if without specify the __dirname, I mean, using `gulp.src('src/*')`?

Comment: Gulp just uses glob and it'll use the gulp.js directory as the root.
You can either enter the path directly `gulp.src('dir/file')` or using the dot to be more clear it uses the current directory `gulp.src('./dir/file')`
https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

Answer (score 0):

I would think - because I am not a Node.js expert - that Gulp uses the current working directory.
The directory which contains the `package.json` and the Gulp script.

So, when invoking Gulp in the app/gulp directory, you can get away with this:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/*')
      .pipe() ...//other code
});
```

You can also use relative paths from that dir, like this:

```
gulp.task('other', function() {
    return gulp.src('../../whatever/*')
      .pipe() ...//other code
});
```